# Custom Post Types: How-to get rid of editor (-meta box)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, editor

I'm questioning how i can **get rid of the post-editor** (visual + html). I tried to not register post type support, and it still appears (de-registering works fine with every other default meta box on post edit screen). I also tried to deregister it with remove_meta_box, which didn't work too (works for everything else except the title meta box). Maybe i'm missing something. Already searched the web and couldn't find anything. I hope someone can tell me. Thanks!

Ps. I would be happy about a sollution for disabling the title field too, but that's 2nd (not registering it with the post type works).

*(Wordpress version is 3.0.4.)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Giving a blank array to 'supports' in the declaration of the post type should get rid of the editor and the title, along with every other default box in the edit post page.

```
$supports = array ('');
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'people',
      'supports' => $supports,
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'public' => true,
      'rewrite' => true
         );

    register_post_type( 'people', $args);
```

Result:
[image]
Populate 'supports' with whichever elements you want to show up, such as trackbacks, comments, etc.  Or just leave it blank to leave the page empty, except for the box that lets you save your posts.  Make sure to visit [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/how-do-you-remove-a-category-style-hierarchical-taxonomy-metabox) if you want to get rid of hierarchical taxonomy metaboxes as well.

Comment: Thanks so far. My problem is that i can't set everything to empty. I wrote three classes to speed up the generation of custom post types, custom taxonomies & tags. They got defaults. In the case of custom post types it's simply everything. But i need to deregister some boxes for specific post types. And for one i need to deregister the editor box too.

Comment: I'm interested in what do you mean by setting everything to empty?  If you want to get rid of the editor, just don't put in ;editor' into the 'supports' array when you create the post type in your class.

Comment: @kaiser if it's your own classes what is the issue? Make them handle it?..

Comment: @Rarst: It's only a base that makes the following things: register post types and taxonomies from an array and offering a filter for $labels and $args (default and specific). The terms class only generates non-deleteable terms that update and asign from an array. Meta boxes can be easy without the class and wouldn't make sense for me to integrate. The classes are only there to save me time and hold clients from deleting terms the system needs. But thanks for looking. Your help is highly appreciated (again) :)

Comment: @Manny Fleurmond: I reuse the classes in different setups (part of my framework). I don't want to change the default "supports all" behavior. I got filters to change that for all post types or only specific ones (override or add to $args). They work for everything, but not for the editor. I also tried the remove_meta_box function without any success (for title meta box too).

Comment: That sounds sorta rigid.  You might want to right your class so that you can change some default settings on an instance to instance basis.  That way you have better control of what shows up when you create a custom post type.

Comment: @kaiser the point of default arguments is that you can override them with non-default when necessary. Otherwise they are not default, but hardcoded and this is rigid setup indeed.

Comment: @Rarst: I guess you got me wrong. I set a filter after labels and args like the following example. They $args include everything except the permalink structure which is set according to the option in the db after the filter. So no, it's not hard coded.

// Filter for all custom post types (change default behavior)
$args = apply_filters( 'config_cpt_args', $args );
// Filter for a specific custom post types
$args = apply_filters( 'config_cpt_args_'.$post_type_name, $args );

Comment: @kaiser then what is the problem with setting `supports` to empty array via filter?

Comment: @Rarst: That the editor (& title) simply don't want to disappear...

Comment: @Rarst: Some "sort of" sollution as the 3rd answer...

Comment: Just gave this one another try - it works.

Comment: Glad that helped!

Answer (score 18):

If you pass nothing for the `supports` argument, [the default settings of `'title', 'editor'` is used](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/post.php#L847) (where "nothing" is anything that is `empty()`).

However, just like you can add support for something after registering the post type with [`add_post_type_support( $post_type, $feature )`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/post.php#L980), you can remove support for something by calling [`remove_post_type_support( $post_type, $feature )`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/post.php#L1006). So calling this after registering your post type should remove the editor:

```
remove_post_type_support( 'my_post_type', 'editor' );
```

These functions just manipulate the global `$_wp_post_type_features` variable, but it's always better to do this with API functions than to fiddle with it yourself.

Comment: SOLLUTION! I always thought this was just to remove ex. thumbnails or nav_menu via a child theme. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ouch, I missed that. Good point, passing empty array will evaluate to empty... Passing empty values is always such a mess, it is counter-intuitive so that is treated like _default_ instead of _nothing_. :(

Comment: @Rarst: I think it would also work if you passed a dummy feature name. It's just an array key, so it doesn't matter if dummy data gets inserted. I [once used `0.1` instead of `0` for a parameter](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-to-show-a-single-post-on-the-front-page-but-have-normal-paging/237#237) to pass the `empty()` check.

Comment: @Jan Fabry yep, it's just not the first time I stepped on `empty()` mine. As above - highly counter-intuitive.

Comment: Hm. It's not working with keys and therefore i think "dummy values" could become another "mine" when upgrading later (try to find the bad value). Anyway: thanks a lot to both of you! :)

Edit: would be handy if the values wouldn't just be there, but are key/value pairs. Ex. `'support' => array('thumbnail' => true, 'editor' => false);`

Comment: Nice answer, @Jan.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Custom Post Type UI plugin to create custom post types.  Using this plugin, you can disable the post-editor under the advanced options.

Manage Post Type -> View Advanced Options

Here is a link to the plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

PS - It lets you disable the title field too :)

Comment: As said above, i wrote three classes and therefore can't switch to a plugin. I mean i wouldn't even consider using a plugin anyway. Plugins are (imo) for development or easy interchangeable stuff like comment forms and not core stuff like post types or taxonomies. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Actually plugins are able to customize pretty much anything about Wordpress, including custom post types.  I'm creating a plugin right now that creates numerous post types, their metaboxes and their various custom fields.

Comment: @Manny Fleurmond: If you are going to share, pls drop me a link. I'm still thinking about maybe-maybe writing a routine for advanced meta-boxes in my classes too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [register_post_type();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) in the codex. Under the **Arguments** section scroll down until you see **Supports**.

As of 3.5, boolean `false` can be passed as value **instead of an array to prevent default** (title and editor) behavior.

Or customize your custom post type how you want by adding in the values you want for example:

```
'supports' => array(
    'title',
    'author',
    'thumbnail',
    'post-formats'
),
```

These supported options in my array will appear in my wordpress backend.

Answer (score -2):

You may also set style for admin edit page to hide sertain elements, such as editor etc.

```
function custom_colors() {
   echo '<style type="text/css">
            body.post-type-events #postdivrich {
            display: none;
            }
         </style>';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'custom_colors');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this would (a) make it non removable as it's not registered with the Dependencies API and (b) make it accessible for people who know how to use the browsers developer tools.